# Droplist field type and Drop link field both are showing Item ID in sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: sxa, solr, content-search, sxa-search

I am using sitecore 9.0.1 and sxa version 1.7. I have created a custom template with field type Drop link for the search functionality and created a rendering varient for it .But it is displaying Item ID of the field. Tried changing the field type to droplist but still the issue is same. can someone help me with this.

[image]

Comment: Is the selected value actually in the selection list ? And is your selected Item published ? It looks the default behavior of when switching from Treelist(or else) with valid item to Droplist with same item..

Comment: https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/extend-search.html#_Extend_search_to_3

Comment: yes the selected value is in the selection list and i tried first with tag treelist datatype but after every change i have rebuilt my indexes also. @Jean-NicolasG

Answer (score 2):

You need to check this part of the documentation: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/setting_up_and_configuring/configuring/extend_search#_Extend_search_to_3

This explains how to use a link type field in the facets. Add a computed field and use that fieldname in the facet:

> Add the following definition to your search configuration file:

```
<field fieldName="referenced"
  type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.ResolvedLinks, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search" 
  referenceField="link"
  contentField="title"/>
```

> where:
>
> fieldName – attribute that defines the index field name where the
> value will be stored.
>
> referenceField – attribute that defines the field name of the indexed
> item.
>
> contentField – attribute that defines the field of the referenced item
> from which the value will be retrieved during the indexing.

Don't forget to rebuild your index after the change.

And change your facet to use the newly created field in your index instead of the original one.

Comment: where can i find my search configuration file under "Appconfig/include/foundation/sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search"? @Gatogordo

Comment: Please explain the above 3 fields with example i am getting confused which field names i have to provide. In my case "fieldname" refers to the template fieldname with data type droplist , "reference field" is the solr indexed name and "contentField" is the template field name where i am storing my data values ..Am i right?@Gatogordo

Comment: Fieldname is the field you choose for the new index field. ReferenceField is the name of your droplink field. contentField is the fieldname in the referenced item that you want to use for display (eg. Title).

Comment: And to see the solr config, you need Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Solr.config (not sure where it is located in a 1.7). But remember to patch the changes, do not change the original config file.

Comment: This is not working @Gatogordo <field fieldName="color_sm" type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.ResolvedLinks, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search"  referenceField="color"contentField="Color"/>.I added this solr search config file but still i am getting the Item ID of the fields not its values or name.

Comment: Did you verify the field in Solr? And did you change your facet to use the new field instead? ps: I wouldn't call the new field "color_sm" - that is going to be confusing.